Flask-login carrying over to other devices/browsers
I been trying to create a web app for todo lists as learning project. I launched it on a server with cpanel. Got everything to work, but now when I login, anyone else that visits the site is logged in to the same account. When I logout it logs everyone out. Could anyone point me in the right way so that a login is only for that persons browser/device. I have no clue what i'm missing/what is causing these issuess.
edit: 1 thing i forgot, on my local system when i open the server in chrome and incognito the login does not carry over and logging out on 1 of the 2 does not log out the other.
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager, current_user
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from database.tables import db, Users
from blueprints.auth.views import auth_bp
from blueprints.lists.views import lists_bp
from blueprints.tasks.views import tasks_bp
from blueprints.groups.views import groups_bp
from active_invites import get_amount_invites

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
app.app_context().push()

db.init_app(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# Flask_login stuff
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"

app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix="/auth")
app.register_blueprint(lists_bp, url_prefix="/lists")
app.register_blueprint(tasks_bp, url_prefix="/tasks")
app.register_blueprint(groups_bp, url_prefix="/groups")


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return db.session.get(Users, int(user_id))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    active_page = "index"
    active_invites = None
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        active_invites = get_amount_invites()

    return render_template(
        "index.html", active_page=active_page, active_invites=active_invites
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

Login in on 1 device, go to the site on a different device and I expected that device to not be logged in on first visit, however it was.
Edit, also showing login and logout user functions:
@auth_bp.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    active_page = "login"

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            # Lookup user
            user = Users.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
            if user:
            # Check the hash
                if check_password_hash(user.password_hash, form.password.data):
                    login_user(user)
                    return redirect(url_for("auth.account"))
                else:
                    flash("Wrong Password - Try Again!")
            else:
                flash("That Username Doesn't Exist! Try Again!")
        except PendingRollbackError:
            # If a pending rollback error occurs, roll back the transaction
            db.session.rollback()
            flash("An error occurred while logging in. Please try again.")

    return render_template("login.html", form=form, active_page=active_page)


@auth_bp.route("/logout", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash("You Logged Out!")
    return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))


I shouldn't have deleted my previous comment. You haven't decorated def index() with @login_required

Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it out, it did not fix the problem of login data carrying over to other browsers/devices. I did not have it decorated at first cause i want people who are not logged in to be able to see the index page. I use if current_user.is_authenticated so that when someone is logged in it shows a badge next to the invites button in my navbar.

How many users do you have? Not devices, actual users with separate logins

Also you haven't shown the actual login_user(), logout_user() mechanisms

Currently got 2 separate users, and i just now added the functions I didn't include earlier.

I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas on this one
